# How fread function takes input from stdin

Tags: c

```
c=fread(&ch,sizeof(char),100,stdin);
```

Will it stop reading from stdin if we give a string "stackoverflow" and hit enter or it will wait untill it gets 100 characters???

Comment: You know that you could *try* this, right?

Comment: `man 3 fread` would help, too.

Answer (score 2):

It will read only the first 100 chars